# return tuple from a method

Tags: python

I am writing a method which returns a tuple on success but `None` on failure. I have not yet finalized on `None` (as a failure case return) but it is one of the choices. Can we return `-1,-1` for failure case? I am looking for best pythonic way to achieve this so that unpacking is easy.

Please let me know how we can improve it. Pseudo code is given below

```
 def myFunc(self):
     if self.validate() != 0:
         return
     x,y = self.getXY()

     return x,y
```

Comment: Why?  What's wrong with raising an exception?

Answer (score 14):

If there is a failure, why don't you raise an exception?

You can of course return (-1, -1) as failure, but it would not be a good solution in my opinion.

Remember that in Python EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) is favoured over LBYL (Look Before You Leap).

This means that it is considered better to just write code under the hypothesis that all works and then catching the appropriate exceptions.

Your code could then become

```
 def myFunc(self):
     if self.validate() != 0:
         raise CustomNotValidatedException()
     x,y = self.getXY()

     return x,y
```

I would improve your code in the following ways:

- make self.validate() return 0 when the result is not positive, so that you can change the second row in a more pythonic way:

  ```
   if not self.validate():
  ```
- remove the intermediate `x, y` variables by changing the return statement to:

  ```
   return self.getXY()
  ```

Finally, you could just raise the exception inside `getXY()` and use directly this method in your code.

Comment: You mean raise the exception within `validate()`, perhaps? I assume `getXY()` here is either not intended as part of the public interface (all the naming is kind of weird then, though), or is meant as a stub for posting in place of the real code (although then maybe it really should be refactored into a helper :) ).

Comment: No, I actually mean throw the exception inside `getXY()`, or else the client should be forced to call `validate()` before each call to `getXY()`. I suppose that it's ok to call `getXY()` for the client, though it is difficult to do this reasoning for almost-pseudo code :)

Answer (score 3):

If this is to catch programming errors, then assert is cleaner.

```
def my_function(self):
    assert self.validate()
    return self.x, self.y
```

If it's to catch run-time errors, perhaps with user-provided data, then an exception is better.

```
def my_function(self):
    if not self.validate():
        raise ValidationError
    return self.x, self.y
```

A good alternative here would for self.validate() to raise validation errors itself: this would allow for example a message to be provided giving the reason for the validation error.