# Finding the average of a function with two parameters

Tags: python, parameters

I'm relatively new to python and had a quick question about the code I'm trying to write...

I'm finding the average of the values of two lists: latitude and longitude. Here's my code:

```
def ave_list(lat_list, long_list):
    sum = 0.0 
    for num in lat_list:
        sum = sum + num
    ave_lat = sum / len(lat_list)
    return ave

def main():
    print ave_list([47.7, 37.0, 32.9, 32.0, 40.0, 41.0, 41.4, 41.8, 0.2, 31.8, -6.3])
main()
```

So I understand how to find the average if I just had one parameter, but I don't know how to write the code with two parameters. If I run this function, it tells me that ave_list() takes exactly 2 arguments but I only gave one. I understand that, but again, I'm not sure how to get separate averages with the two parameters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [`statistcs.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to redefine `ave_list` to take a single list, and from main, call it once for latitude and once for longitude:

```
def ave_list(mylist):
    sum = 0.0 
    for num in mylist:
        sum = sum + num
    ave = sum / len(mylist)
    return ave
```

Python allows a function to return two values as a tuple, so you could recode your original function to return (ave_lat, ave_lon).  But why add that complication?  Here it is for learning purposes, though:

```
def ave_list(lat_list, long_list):
    sum = 0.0 
    for num in lat_list:
        sum = sum + num
    ave_lat = sum / len(lat_list)
    sum = 0.0 
    for num in lon_list:
        sum = sum + num
    ave_lon = sum / len(lon_list)
    return (ave_lat, ave_lon)

alat, alon = ave_list([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])
print(alat, alon)
```

Of course, as @bla points out in a comment, better to use `statistics.mean`:

```
import statistics
alat = statistics.mean([1,2,3,4])
alon = statistics.mean([5,6,7,8])
print(alat, alon)
```

It's in python3; not sure about python2.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the error you should pass two values to your function. Instead of using it a better approach would be with [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
from statistics import mean
>>> mean([1, 2, 3])
2
>>> mean([1, 2, 3.0])
2.0
```

If that module is not available you may use:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sum(data) / len(data)
2
```

if you have only ints and want the result as float in python2 just convert one of the sides to float:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 7]
>>> sum(data) / len(data)
3
>>> sum(data) / float(len(data))
3.25
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `long_list` from `ave_list` since it isn't even used.

If you want to calculate the **separated** mean of two lists you can either call `ave_list` twice, one call passing each list or making `ave_list` retur mutiple values (as a tuple, for an example)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing that you do for a list, do for the other, and return 2 values as a *tuple*. ([[SO]: return tuple from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873613/return-tuple-from-a-method)
)

Here's an implementation that uses [[Python]: **sum**(*iterable[, start]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). 
Note that it can be written in a much more compact manner, but I'm keeping all steps separate, so it's clearer:

```
def ave_list(lat_list, long_list):
    lat_sum = sum(lat_list)  # Calculate the sum
    if len(lat_list):  # Test so we don't divide by 0
        lat_avg = lat_sum / len(lat_list)  # Calculate avg
    else:
        lat_avg = 0  # List empty, consider avg 0
    long_sum = sum(long_list)  # Same thing for longitude
    if len(long_list):
        long_avg = long_sum / len(long_list)
    else:
        long_avg = 0
    return lat_avg, long_avg
```

The results can be retrieved via *tuple unpacking* (check [[Python]: Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)):

```
lat_ave, long_ave = ave_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])
```

and this should give you ***2.0*** for `lat_ave`, and ***4.0*** for `long_ave`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers, you can have a two argument function to calculate the average latitude & longitude as follows

Using `statistics.mean`

```
import statistics
def ave_lat_long(lat_list, long_list):
    return(statistics.mean(lat_list),statistics.mean(long_list))
```

Example of storing returned tuple of average latitude & longitude in separate variables (tuple unpacking)

```
ave_lat,ave_long= ave_lat_long([47.7, 37.0, 32.9],[40.0, 41.0, 41.4])
```

Printing average latitude & longitude

```
print ave_lat_long([47.7, 37.0, 32.9],[40.0, 41.0, 41.4])
```

Result (in console)

```
(39.2, 40.8)
```

Or, defining your own mean function as `ave_list`:

```
def ave_list(coordinate_list):
    sum = 0.0 
    for num in coordinate_list:
        sum = sum + num
    ave_list = sum / len(coordinate_list)
    return round(ave_list,1)
```

Then define the function for average latitude & longitude

```
def ave_lat_long(lat_list,long_list):
    return (ave_list(lat_list),ave_list(long_list))
```

Printing average latitude & longitude

```
print(ave_lat_long([47.7, 37.0, 32.9],[40.0, 41.0, 41.4]))
```

Result (in console)

```
(39.2, 40.8)
```